# Create universal framework with dependencies

Tags: swift, sdk, frameworks

I have a project, with a `framework` target - source code written in `swift`. This target uses another target - another framework, with closed source. Everything works fine, but I have a problem with creating an `universal framework` - compiled so that it can be added to projects. I have tried various methods found one the internet, but none works. Can someone help me with this? I have created aggregate target, but can't find a script for it, which will build all the required frameworks. Maybe someone have some tested scripts I could use?

Comment: Do you want to use some dependencies in the framework you are developing? Is that the issue you are facing?